# Gnuplot construct timefmt from different CSV columns?

Tags: linux, csv, timestamp, gnuplot

I have the following `csv` file in which the columns represent `hour`,`minute`,`view count` respectively, exactly 1440 entries for every minute of the day. I would like to plot it using `gnuplot`. (Putting the HH:MM into one column is not possible due to the MySQL ONLY FULL GROUP BY.)

```
"0","0","71"
"0","1","55"
"0","2","56"
...
"23","57","66"
"23","58","70"
"23","59","75"
```

Currently I use the following commands:

```
set datafile separator ","
set timefmt "%H,%M"
set xdata time 
set xtics format "%H:%M" time font "/:normal,8" rotate by 45 offset -1,-1
```

The time format is not rendered correctly, the hours are interpreted as minutes and the minutes are not shown at all.
I also tried `set timefmt "\"%H\",\"%M\""` without success.

[image: x plotting timestamps]

Two questions:

- How can I parse the hour:minute and display it correctly?
- If this data file had more columns and the timestamp was not in the first but in the n-th one, then how can I specify for gnuplot to render that, similar to `using 0:n` for `plot`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this time format string

```
set timefmt "%H:%M"
```

Put this function somewhere:

```
catdate(x,y)=sprintf("%d:%d",x,y)
```

Then plot with:

```
plot 'data.dat' u (catdate($1,$2)):($3) w l
```